# LeetCode easy problem but a confused clarification to solve the return type from the function

Tags: python, list

Last night, i have tried some of this type of easy problems in leetcode. Though, till now i have tried almost 20 problems in leetcode, and all of them, examples and clarifications are well discussed or easy to understand. But when i tried this problem [26. Remove duplicates from sorted array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/), at first look, i tried to understand the description.

After a little bit, it becomes harder for me to well understood, then i tried to understand the examples and clarification, it seems more complex for me.

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        nums = list(set(nums))
        temp = 0
        print(nums)
        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp += 1
        return temp
```

But from my side, i tried to understand and solve the problem and tried this way to solve the problem, but i don't know where's my problem? As they consider the return type as int and it's the length of the list size after removing the duplicates. But when i run my code, i seems like this,
[image]

Here my stdout is as like their expected output, then why not my output isnt like them?
From their description, they have said that they are expecting int type return value, and also it is declared in their function output declaration is return type will be int, then why they show me list type expected output?

Please explain my problem in details so that i can understand the problem and give me a solution to think about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question requires that you **modify the input list [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)**. Instead, your current code `nums = list(set(nums))` creates a **new list** that is only visible inside the function, not to the caller.

So it is not enough to return the length of the list — you must also modify the original list.

You can imagine that leetcode is doing something like this:

```
nums = [1,1,2]
length = Solution().removeDuplicates(nums)
expected = nums[:length]
```

Since you have not modified `nums`, and `length` is 2, your "actual" output is `nums[:2] == [1,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As question said, you need to return distinct number of elements that is correct om your part, but another thing question mentioned is you need to.do it inplace, no extra memory overhead and you are clearly allocating new list instead of using old one.

In simple words use loops instead of built-in utilities/functionalities.